# Can't open Ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

I've installed the following version of Ubuntu om my machine:

```
ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

But when I switch on the computer, I get the command line.

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ubuntu tty6
```

Once I provide my username and password, it authenticates and then displays a link to documentation.

Now, how can I start a GUI? Am I stuck at the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly try  Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch to GUi .If this doesn't work, type startx to start a new session.

If you tried the command startx, but the error command not found was returned, then to install a graphical desktop, in case it is not installed, you would type this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This should work, else try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```